# "You took... and you..."

Tags: meaning, grammar

How would the grammar of this construction be analysed? I am trying to identify and define the difference between using this and the regular way of saying the same thing.

Examples:

- You took this place and you transformed it / You transformed this place
- You took that song and butchered it / You butchered that song
- You took my trust and abused it / You abused my trust
- Alcohol took my life and destroyed it / Alcohol destroyed my life
- The internet took society and transformed it / The Internet transformed society

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a subtle difference. The word "take" is used in these sentences to mean *taking ownership* or *taking responsibility*. To *take* something and *then* do something to it implies that the *taker* has done the action intentionally, or is at least directly responsible for the outcome.

For example, it is possible to *transform a place* by simply being there, or by passing through, but to *take a place and transform it* suggests that something deliberate has been done in order to affect that transformation.

It gets a bit more complicated with non-living subjects such as *Alcohol* and *The Internet*, but the principle is the same:

The sentence "Alcohol destroyed my life" can be interpreted to mean: [The use of] *alcohol destroyed my life*. or *Alcohol* [abuse] *destroyed my life*, both of which leave the responsibility with the drinker.

The sentence "Alcohol took my life and destroyed it" explicitly personifies the alcohol (by making it the *taker*) and *then* assigns blame to it.